# How do I stop Microsoft Office from associating an Outlook.com com email address used in Outlook with all my MS Office Products (Word, Excel, etd)

Tags: windows-10, email, microsoft-outlook-2016, microsoft-office-2016

This has started to really annoy me and just started happening a few week / a month ago or something like that.  I have a few different outlook.com email addresses I use for different personal purposes.  Most of them work fine, but lately two of them keep prompting me for my password when I open Outlook 2016.  After I put in my password I get this screen - very annoying:[image]

If I click Next, it automatically signs me into Word, Excel, etc with this account.  I don't want it to do that.  I just want Outlook to use that account and for the other office products to continue without an account.  If I click Microsoft app only - SAME THING.  If I close the window, I have to enter my password the next time i open Outlook.  [ANNOYING!!!!]  My other accounts do not have this problem.  How do I fix this?

I have Office 2016 - Version 1908 / Build 11929.20254.  This is on a Windows 10 pro machine.

Comment: That would appear to be the Office Subscription Live Account for all of Office. If you use just this account and make the other accounts manual, then Outlook should not require a password. That is the way it works for me.

Comment: Are you 100% you have not unknowingly subscribed to Office 365?

Comment: I don't know how to check that I have signed up for Office 365, but considering that is a fee based service, I highly doubt it since I have not paid for anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

There is [an explanation](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/84e663ad-7c70-42ff-8e92-7368f22407ae/prompt-use-this-account-everywhere-on-your-device-what-causes-it?forum=onlineservicesexchange) in this thread:

If you are using Office in Windows 10, issue could occur when Sync settings is turned on. Windows syncs the settings you choose across all your Windows 10 devices that you've signed in to with your Microsoft account.

You could try to stop syncing your settings and remove them from the cloud, then keep monitoring the issue and see if it will re-appear.

Comment: Considering I don't use a Microsoft account to sign into my machine, I don't think that is it.  Now I am finding that periodically somehow when I go to Settings and account, it has one of these two problem emails listed as the account in use.